# Usage of て-form in 知っての通り

Tags: grammar, nuances

I have just come across the phrase `知っての通り〜` (as you know...)

I have never noticed this usage of て-form before and can't find an explanation.

What is the difference (if any) between this and `知っている通り`?

I have also seen `見ての通り` used in a similar way.

If possible please provide a more generalised explanation of the grammar at work here, and examples of other ways it may be used.

Comment: I thought the answer posted yesterday seemed reasonable. Why did the poster choose to delete it? Did it turn out to be incorrect or something?

Comment: @ジョン I pointed out that て in てこと is an entirely different thing.

Comment: Hmm when we say 「ご存知(ぞんじ？)の通り・ご承知の通り・お聞きの通り・ご覧の通り」, 「ご存知・ご承知・お聞き・ご覧」 are nouns... Can 知って be a noun??

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for the comment. That's exactly what I was wondering, but I'm not familiar with that usage of て-form. It's not specific to 知って as I've also seen 見ての通り.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a brief description of this in 日本文法大辞典 (Matsuura Akira, 1971) on page 505.

> 「て」は、多くの接続助詞と異なり、すべての係助詞、副助詞「のみ」「だに」「すら」、格助詞「の」「より」「から」などを下接する。[略] 格助詞に。例：あひ見**ての**後の心にくらぶれば昔はものを思はざりけり (拾遺集 710) / 生レ**テヨリ**コノカタ (中華若木詩抄・中) / 提婆ハヲサナウ**テカラ**仏ト中カワルカツタソ (勅規桃源鈔, 3)

Rough translation:

> -*te* differs from many other conjunctive particles in that it can be suffixed by all linking particles; adverbial particles -*nomi*, -*dani*, -*sura*; and case particles -*no*, -*yori*, -*kara*, etc. [skip] Case particles: (Examples) あひ見**ての**後の心にくらぶれば昔はものを思はざりけり (拾遺集 710), 生レ**テヨリ**コノカタ (中華若木詩抄・中), 提婆ハヲサナウ**テカラ**仏ト中カワルカツタソ (勅規桃源鈔, 3)

As already noted, in modern Japanese the two most common forms are *mite no tōri* and *sitte no tōri*. As explained above, this is just one of many suffixes that -*te* can take on.

There is a fine explanation comparing *mite no tōri*, *mita tōri*, and *miru tōri* [here](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q116469966).

Comment: Great answer - thanks!
You say those are the two most common forms. Are there any others, or would that form with any other verbs be out-of-place in modern Japanese?

Comment: Sure, there are others. I can recall 聞いての通り, 読んでの通り, and 立っての通り. In the right context, there are surely others as well. If you want to widen the scope, there are plenty of other "-te no" constructions. Examples include （影響を受け）ての（対応）, （～に向け）ての（準備）, and （命あっ）ての（物種）. These are all productive and can be used to create other expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up!  Really useful. If it can be used this freely I'm starting to think I must have seen it before and glossed over it without questioning it :p

Comment: @Dono Btw when you say "linking particles", are you referring to kakari-joshi?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes. Please refer to the Japanese original directly above that. Quote: すべての係助詞...

Comment: @Dono Ic, thanks for the clarification =)