# てはin this sentence

Tags: grammar

あわせて、あちらの黒いズボンもはいてみ**ては**どうですか。

Context is a salesperson asking a customer to try out a pair of pants (in addition to a jacket he is already wearing).

Is the ては in this sentence ています in subject form? (I'm still not sure how this works though, can someone explain haha)

Thank you!

Comment: は is not a subject marker.

Comment: so is てはどうですか an expression on its own? If so what is its meaning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

-て is a special form because it can be suffixed by certain particles like は or の (see [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5212)). You are probably also familiar with its use in phrases like -てはいけない.

-てはどうですか is more or less a set expression meaning "how about (doing something)". You can also replace どう with いかが to make it sound more polite, and drop the ですか to make it sound more familiar (leaving just どう).

So, your sentence translates to:

> How about trying on those black pants, too?